# Resolving classpath with ant's taskdef and running only required target

Tags: ant, classpath, taskdef

my *main-build.xml* looks like:

```
<path id="run.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${build.lib.dir}/ant-{version}.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${third-party.lib.dir}/some-{my-ver}.jar"/>
</path>
```

*deploy.xml* uses taskdef ant task on one of class present inside third-party jar:

```
<taskdef name="run-third-party-exec" classname="package.name.ThirdPartyExec"/>
```

*sub-build.xml* imports *main-build.xml* & `deploy.xml` and tries to run a ant target present in deploy.xml but fails complaining

```
taskdef package.name.ThirdPartyExec cannot be found
```

How to resolve such problem. Since all taskdefs & imports get executed when we import a file prior to executing a target its failing. Not sure on adding all complaining thirdparty jar's to ant's classpath is right way or not?.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<taskdef>` needs to know where to find `package.name.ThirdPartyExec`. Do this by providing the classpath:

```
<taskdef 
    name="run-third-party-exec" 
    classname="package.name.ThirdPartyExec" 
    classpathref="run.classpath" 
/>
```

Comment: third-party jar(s) are added to ant's classpath in main-build.xml & hence classpathref is not mentioned in deploy.xml when taskdef call is made. And calling a target of deploy.xml from sub-build.xml fails, since it does not find required jar in ant's classpath

Comment: By itself, your `<path id="run.classpath">` in main-build.xml doesn't add anything to any classpaths. After Ant has started, there is no way to add to "Ant's classpath." Individual tasks can have their own classpaths. That's what `classpathref` provides--a way for tasks to have their own classpaths. Your scripts need to be structured so the `<path id="run.classpath">` runs first and then the `run.classpath` reference can be passed to tasks that need it. See [the Optional Tasks section of Installing Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#optionalTasks) for further background.